# Validate portal users using OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth2, portal

How can i validate portal users using OAuth 2.0?
My current implementation is to send request to login.salesforce.com as :

`https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=MyConsumerKey&client_secret=MyConsumerSecret&username='+username+'&password='+password`

This works fine for non- portal users.
However, the request doesn't work for portal users.
The response sent back is

> {"error_description":"authentication failure - Unknown exception:
>   1201","error":"invalid_grant"}

I tried to change the `login.salesforce.com` to the `communityURL` which is 'cqdev-developer-edition.na17.force.com' as suggested by 'http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/quickstart_communities.htm', but the problem still exists.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Does this happen for only grant_type=password or other types too ?

Comment: I haven't tried with other types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For community/portal users why not use

> Site.login(username, password,startUrl)

to validate that the username and password are indeed valid.

It returns an error on the page if the username and password aren't valid. And redirects to a page if they are valid.

You can use

> ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity)

method to check if the page has an invalid username/password message.

Answer (score 0):

Its important to know what endpoint you are using. Is it -
**{siteurl}/services/oauth2/authorize**

Comment: Shouldn't this read a ``{siteurl}/customers/services/oauth2/authorize`` ?